# pause/resume Recording

Tags: java, video-recording

I'm using a trial version of JXCapture API.
Is it possible to pause recording, and then resume it (and have a single 
output video at the end)? This is a requirement for the program I'm 
writing using JXCapture.
I couldn't do that with VideoCapture class, since it only contains 
start() , stop() and pause() methods.
I tried the pause() method but how to resume it I am not getting the idea.
In the class VideoCapture there is no such method for resume it.

Comment: @KenY-N Looks like the related `pause()` message is actually the correct one. The `doX()` methods are protected.

Comment: `VideoCapture` *does* have a [pause() method](https://www.teamdev.com/downloads/jxcapture/javadoc/com/teamdev/jxcapture/VideoCapture.html#pause())

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt VideoCapture has pause method

Comment: In your question you say that VideoCapture only contains a start and a stop method, not a pause method. And now you say it does have a pause method. Then it looks like you no longer have a question. In that case it's better to delete it.

Comment: You just edited the question to say that the class contains a pause method, but why don't you actually *use* the pause method? Try start-pause-start-stop

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Sorry for that .....but it does not have a resume method to resume my recording please suggest me for that

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt please suggest me to resume it

Comment: @RANJEETGIRI Please read @Erwin's comment again - try using `start()` to restart.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Thanks for giving the suggetion it really helped me

Comment: @KenY-N Thank you

Comment: @KenY-N when i use the pause() , start () method on the jbutton and press 4 or five time the jframe get hang. please help me.........